# Can't install php5-curl, getting "404 Not found" errors

Tags: server, virtualbox, php

My problem when trying to install `php5-curl` on my virtual box linux server.
I did `ifconfig eth1 up`:

```
err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main php5-curl amd64 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 
404 not found
err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main php5-curl amd64 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
404 Not found {ip: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

Comment: It looks like the mirrors you are using (or your system) is broken, as `php5-curl` does exist in the repositories and exists on other mirrors... what was the command you used to install, `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`?

Comment: @thomasW. I did the following `ifconfig eth 1`

`apt-get install php5-curl`

Comment: It looks like whatever mirror(s) you're using are broken, you may want to switch to different archive mirrors, since the publishing history of `php5-curl` show its actually in the mirrors, as does `apt-get install php5-curl` from the US mirrors I use (I'm in the US, though, hence using US mirrors)

Comment: @thomasw. how should I change the mirrors?

Answer (score 2):

first run sudo apt-get update on a terminal, and after install again. If problem persist, change the source to principal server on software origin, and then update and install again.